# .htaccess sef pagination link to query string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url structure as xxxx.com/blog/page/1. But pagination gives 404. I need to rewrite it with .htaccess as xxxx.com/blog?page=1. Can you help me?

`RewriteRule ^blog/page/([0-9]+)$ blog?page=$1 [R=302,L]`
i try this rule in htaccess

Comment: And what happens when you try that rule? That rule kind of does what you are asking, except that `/blog?page=1` is not a valid end-point to begin with (so probably isn't what you should be doing) and this is a "redirect", not a "rewrite". However, this is WordPress - you shouldn't have to manually add a rule like that to `.htaccess` to get "pagination" to work?

Comment: @MrWhite in this case [R=302,L] should work when you remove the code block? It doesn't work this way either

Comment: don't do this. adding the page with a query param like `?page=1` is bad for SEO.

Comment: What do you mean by, "when you remove the code block"? If that directive is not doing anything at all then you've likely put it in the wrong place - that rule would need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file _before_ any existing WP rewrites.